# how to set message body size limit for azure custom connector or azure function

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have a workflow where a series of functions are hosted as custom connectors which can be called from logic apps. The azure function has a max message size limit of 100mb. I am passing a 300kb message body which the azure function handles fine when debugging alone , but when the same thing is hosted as custom connector or azure function , it throws this error. I can't find any documentation where to specify the limits for message body size for a  custom connector. Thanks

[image: Logic App connector Output]

**Kindly help**

Comment: The only limit on a custom connector should be the same as the HTTP request limit on Logic Apps (100 MB). The error in your screenshot looks like it originates not from your custom connector or Logic Apps, but your destination service instead. Does investigating there turn up more information?

Comment: The destination service is pointed to a eventhub, i think that is causing the problem. Is there any other way can i achieve this without using eventHub

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to achieve, but at this point we're moving outside my realm of knowledge. I've reached out to someone on the Logic Apps team who will be able to help you more effectively. Please contact him directly at deli@microsoft.com and include your subscription ID, workflow name, and run ID to assist with debugging.